# Bash Create Directories/Subdirectories Using Two Lists

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to create a number of directories, each with a number of subdirectories based on two lists using Bash. Currently, the below code achieves this result:

```
 mkdir -p {P01DH,P02DL,P03NH,P04NL,P05RH,P06RL}/{folder1,folder2,folder3,folder4,folder5,folder6,folder7,folder8}
```

Yields

```
P01DH/folder1
P01DH/folder2 
...
P06RL/folder8
```

**Question:** Is there a cleaner (non-single-line) way to achieve the same result, perhaps storing the two lists as arrays or variables and using loops?

Comment: `P0{1DH,2DL,3NH,4NL,5RH,6RL}/folder{1..8}`

Comment: What do you mean by `cleaner`? What do you consider dirty/haram/not kosher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested loops:

```
for parent in P01DH P02DL P03NH P04NL P05RH P06RL; do
    for child in folder{1..8}; do
        mkdir -p "$parent/$child"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all! Combining @karakfa's and @Barmar's solutions above (and adding the ability to do additional steps within the loop), I get the following:

```
for parent in P0{1DH,2DL,3NH,4NL,5RH,6RL}; do
    for child in folder{1..8}; do
        mkdir -p "$parent/$child"
        cp myfile.py "$parent/$child"
        #do other tasks
    done
done
```